# Limiting data collection of Cachegrind, in Valgrind

Tags: valgrind, cachegrind

It is well known that, the `callgrind` analysis tool of the  `valgrind` suit, provides the possibility to start and stop the colection of data via command line instruction `callgrind_control -i on` or `callgrind_control -i off`. For instance, the following code will collect data only after the hour.

```
(sleep 3600; callgrind_control -i on) &
valgrind --tool=callgrind --instr-atstart=no ./myprog
```

Is there a similar option for the `cachegrind` tool? if so, how can I use it (I do not find anything in the documentation)? If no, how can I start collecting data after a certain amount of time with `cachegrind`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such function for Cachegrind.

However, Callgrind is an extension of Cachegrind, which means that you can use Cachegrind features on Callgrind.

For example:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --cache-sim=yes --branch-sim=yes ./myprog
```

Will measure your programs cache and branch performance as if you where using Cachegrind.